# How can I rename a file when assembling a spring boot project?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have the following assembly.xml. I was trying to figure out how when including files I can rename them to something else. Currently, my tar has the war file as project-1.0.0.0.war and I want it to be project.war. How can I accomplish this?

```
<assembly>
<id>${version}-tar</id>
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
<baseDirectory>project-${version}</baseDirectory>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>project-${version}.war</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>etc/bin</directory>
        <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>start</include>
            <include>stop</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the destination name of the file in the assembly, you shouldn't use a [`<fileSet>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet), but a [`<file>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_file). The reason is that the first groups several files together, and as such, doesn't provide a way to control the name of each file in the group. Since a `<file>` targets only a single file, you can control the destination name with the `<destName>` element:

> Sets the destination filename in the outputDirectory. Default is the same name as the source's file.

You should have instead:

```
<files>
  <file>
    <source>target/project-${version}.war</directory>
    <destName>project.war</destName>
  </file>
</files>
<!-- the other "fileSets" for etc/bin, unchanged -->
```

instead of the `<fileSet>`. This will make sure that the file specified in the `<source>` element is renamed to `<destName>` in the resulting assembly.

Comment: thanks! followup q i guess, if i want to include all files in a directory, what's the proper syntax?

Comment: @iCodeBadly Just don't specify an `<include>` element to the `<fileSet>`; by default it includes everything under the specified directory. If you specifically want files, but not folder, `<include>*</include>` should work

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to add:

```
<build>
    ...
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    ...
</build>
```

[Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html)